# Typesetting a small function with Big parameters

Tags: spacing, symbols, fontsize, delimiters

I have a small function that needs to take big parameters. Right now I think that the function part looks too small and implicitly suggests it might be some kind of multiplication instead of an evaluation.

```
\newcommand{\rect}{\mathrm{\textbf{rect}}}
...
\(\left[(\rect_\ell) \ast (f\ast g)\right]\left( x+\frac{2i-1}{2k},y+\frac{2j-1}{2k}\right)\)
```

It looks like this & I think its ugly:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does a look which uses `\bigl` and `\bigr` instead of `\left` and `\right`, i.e., making sure that the outer brackets and parentheses have the same size, meet your needs?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm} % educated guess about fonts
\usepackage{palatino} 
\newcommand{\rect}{\textbf{rect}} % don't use \mathbf as that would load Computer Modern
\begin{document}
before:

\(\left[(\rect_\ell) \ast (f\ast g)\right]
\left( x+\frac{2i-1}{2k},y+\frac{2j-1}{2k}\right)\)

\medskip

after:

\(\bigl[(\rect_\ell) \ast (f\ast g)\bigr]
\bigl( x+\frac{2i-1}{2k},y+\frac{2j-1}{2k}\bigr)\)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's my proposals; my preferred one would be the last, without outer parentheses.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\rect}{\textbf{rect}} % simplify definition of \rect

\begin{document}
Displayed
\begin{gather}
\bigl[(\rect_{l}) \ast (f\ast g)\bigr]
\bigl(x+\tfrac{1}{2k}(2i-1),y+\tfrac{1}{2k}(2j-1)\bigr)
\\
\bigl(\rect_{l} \ast (f\ast g)\bigr)
\bigl(x+\tfrac{1}{2k}(2i-1),y+\tfrac{1}{2k}(2j-1)\bigr)
\\
\rect_{l} \ast (f\ast g)
\bigl(x+\tfrac{1}{2k}(2i-1),y+\tfrac{1}{2k}(2j-1)\bigr)
\end{gather}
Text:\\[1ex]
$\bigl[(\rect_{l}) \ast (f\ast g)\bigr]
\bigl(x+\tfrac{1}{2k}(2i-1),y+\tfrac{1}{2k}(2j-1)\bigr)$\\[1ex]
$\bigl(\rect_{l} \ast (f\ast g)\bigr)
\bigl(x+\tfrac{1}{2k}(2i-1),y+\tfrac{1}{2k}(2j-1)\bigr)$\\[1ex]
$\rect_{l} \ast (f\ast g)
\bigl(x+\tfrac{1}{2k}(2i-1),y+\tfrac{1}{2k}(2j-1)\bigr)$
\end{document}
```

[image]